# Creating as much fields as selected

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need help with WordPress. I've created custom field called:
`Select number of workers`. And here is select list from 1 to 10;

Now, there is a part where I need help. Is it possible to make as many input fields as the selected number? For example I select 3 workers. And WordPress creates 3 input fields, to type workers name? WordPress is new to me so I don't have much experience in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest if you're not really comfortable with Wordpress to  use a custom fields plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) or [Custom Fields Suite](http://docs.customfieldsuite.com/). With Custom Fields Suite for example, you can create [a loop of fields](http://docs.customfieldsuite.com/field-types/loop.html), set is maximum to 10 then user  can add as much worker as they want up to ten.

Then in the template, you can get the content in this way:

```
$fields = CFS()->get( 'workers' );
foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    echo $field['name'];
}
```